# Instructive contrast in Elizabeth Finch By Julian Barnes

Tags: meaning, elizabeth-finch, julian-barnes

What is meant by "**instructive contrast**" in the following context from "Elizabeth Finch" by Julian Barnes:

> The headline read ‘CRAZY LADY’ PROF CLAIMS ROMAN EMPERORS RUINED OUR
> SEX LIFE. You can easily imagine how EF’s sober facts and speculations
> were turned into scandalous matter. For instance, the poet Swinburne
> was a known homosexual with a taste for flagellation: was that the
> prof’s idea of an honourable English gentleman whose views were worth
> considering? For instance, what on earth did she mean by ‘the closing
> of the European mind’ when it had produced Shakespeare, Leonardo da
> Vinci, Dante, Beethoven, Darwin, Isaac Newton and so on? **Not to
> mention Monty Python, an instructive contrast to the said humourless
> ‘Crazy Lady’**. As for the notion that what you got up to in bed was
> somehow affected by what long-dead Christians and popes had thought
> about it all was, in the words of one editorial commentator, ‘a load
> of bollocks’.

This is a ficitional version of what happened to Hillary Mantel in 2013 (Controversy over Princess of Wales). Here, the papers are attacking EF because of her lecture in London review of books.
I know Monty Python, Bu my question is what is meant by "**instructive contrast**" here? and how can Monty Python be so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting passage!

The sense of 'instruction' used in 'instructive' is basically the same as 'edification' - *to instruct* as in *to teach*; that concept is old-fashioned, but 'instructive' is still used to describe examples. The contrast between Monty Python and EF's (lack of) sense of humour illustrates the criticism being made (i.e. it's instructive), but there several things going on with the Monty Python reference. I'd say that *[Monty Python's Life of Brian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python%27s_Life_of_Brian)* (1979) is the reference, given its historical and satirical relevance.

I liked the passage, so here's a lot of context, bearing in mind that I see two linked themes in it: hypocrisy (contradiction), and *implication*, thrown at EF's explicit commentaries ('sober facts and speculations')... so it's worthwhile to deconstruct (well, it was fun lol).

### Instructive contrast

So the passage is discussing all the mudslinging in the media at once (via free indirect speech). All the arguments are bad; they cite examples of norms to defend those norms (making EF's argument about unconsidered norms already); the references illustrate hypocrisy and closed-mindedness.

The first critic casts Swinburne as dishonourable and un-English because of his sexual (moral) unfitness, dismissing EF by association. The second sentence references arguments that European artists/scientists were worthwhile long after Rome, with examples they may have given (Newton, Dante). Then it adds Monty Python to this list, but in a different context, where the sentence is singling out the specific objection to humourlessness, so that's being commented on itself on its own level.

Just the swerve towards Monty Python highlights the absurdity of the argument. It's also highlighting the cultural bias of a kind of person who might reject an argument simply because it isn't very agreeable. By agreeable I mean something like... lighthearted, in good fun, entertaining and fun to think about, etc. You actually can't put your finger on this, because that's the bias! What you *can* identify is the contrast, specifically why 'humourless' EF is bad. If I had to give words for that, I'd pick 'didactic' and 'moralising' - and this *instructive* (didactic) contrast is moralising. Which is fine, because their morals are normal/good, and EF's are bad. And there's no actual instruction being made, of course (you spotted this), the instruction is an allusion and entirely implicit. The reader shows the work, the writer instructs.

There are a lot of insults for someone who makes an earnest moral argument, and another on-the-nose one is 'lecturing'. Part of this is because it must be superior, which is very important - EF is being cast on several layers as an intellectual snob turning her nose up at the people's morality.

Monty Python, on the other hand, isn't snobbish, it's peak British comedy. It has the very real virtue of having made generations happy.

I also want to point out that the use of Monty Python here is doubly loaded. The passage pits the lowbrow, crass Monty Python against the highbrow, pure European intellectuals... and thus EF herself. By making us laugh at the dramatically ridiculous criticism of EF's personality, we associate liking Monty Python with the personality of the anonymous character who made it (who is one within many, treated mainly via association). We might think intellectuals act in better faith to begin with, contribute more to society, or that their speech is more honest because it deals with 'sober facts and speculations'.

Intellectuals have plenty of dishonest arguments, of course, and, quite aside from dishonesty, sometimes they just 'reckon' sombrely with ambiguities. HM's Princess Di commentary went too far to be a tasteful eulogy, but it was never going to be a scathing political critique, so it reads as navel-gazing sometimes - because it is.

We can see this parallel by looking at what satire is. Monty Python might be invoked because they're a great example of people who are held up for destroying sacred cows - and you can't really do that and be as widely revered as Monty Python. In fact, every single person in that list is treated as entirely inoffensive, except Swinburne (a dramatic counterexample).

#### What have the Romans ever done for us? and absurdity

If comedy doesn't have a point, are you supposed to draw a conclusion? Well... you can't get around it, and comedy is held as particularly sacred in this regard. Comedy is innocent; it just wants to make people feel better, whether it's a pun or an offensive joke. Yet comedy is powerful; it speaks truth to power, doesn't it, it's satire?

Satire as a genre really exemplifies this whole problem. Satire is subtle as a way of mocking the absurd (overt), which it exaggerates. Satire is a genre where the existence of irony is itself meant as a criticism, rather than any more direct point - even though ironies and contradictions are myriad in real life, because real life is complex. The reason satire can do this and be good is because you can draw your own conclusion from what it points out - although what makes a satirist clever is their ability to make their own point (subtly), so one could paint this as a cooperative style of argument, rather than an instructive style. It certainly feels better to most people.

We imagine the wittiest satire as sneaking past the target, yet not the reader. You know, satires made of repressive societies get upheld as criticisms of the societies simply because the repression necessitated the satire. We blend together the society, the author's own life, and the author's work, because they're all overtly linked. But it's not like tyrants are actually clueless about being the butt of a popular joke; it's more like the satirist is taking an exaggerated tiptoe past the subject to begin with. And that isn't the same thing as a demonstration that the satirist had to.

Also, sometimes satire is upheld just because it's funny and people like funny things, which really couldn't be more topical.

One of the most-quoted scenes:

> REG: We're giving Pilate two days to dismantle the entire apparatus of the Roman Imperialist State, and if he doesn't agree immediately, we execute her.

...

> REG: All right, but apart from the sanitation, the medicine, education, wine, public order, irrigation, roads, a fresh water system, and public health, what have the Romans ever done for us?
>
> XERXES: Brought peace.
>
> REG: Oh. Peace? Shut up!

TV Tropes has an article named after this quote: [What the Romans Have Done for Us](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatTheRomansHaveDoneForUs)  ; it illustrates quite well that this observation is used to make all sorts of arguments, because the situation is a complex one. These arguments include defending imperial occupation because it comes with technological progress and rule of law. One might suppose *Monty Python* has no duty to make an argument, and just uses it to ramp up the absurdism, but it's hard to present information without suggesting *something*. Because there isn't a clear argument in the scene, just whatever the viewer associates with that information, the quote is invoked as a reference to the situation overall - which carries all kinds of implication. Sometimes it's just used to say 'consider that your gut reaction to this situation is wrong when you consider it intellectually', sometimes it says bad things have silver linings, etc.

Pertinently, the quote is often used when listing the achievements of the Romans, like, well, a meme - anyone reaching for the quote is associating it with Romans and sanitation, not the Roman Empire and the occupation of Judea. The quote can be taken so wildly out of context in part because the scene doesn't have to defend itself, merely present the contradiction humorously. And contradictions *are* absurd, so highlighting them has value - except that contradictions like the Roman Empire remain in place (accepted) because they're powerful (literally). So, if you repeat them literally, you'll find plenty of situations where people are actually quite fine with them (subtle or unsubtle!), which is relevant to every layer of this situation. Contradictions, including hypocrisies, aren't inherently wrong; they're complexities which most things (including famous people) possess.

Overall, the movie is satirising Christians who cite Jesus while persecuting others, so isn't that kind of similar to how Jesus's teachings get taken out of context? Hmm... *Life of Brian* intentionally doesn't make fun of Jesus, or oppose any of his teachings. It's no secret that this movie, which just presents everything as ultimately laughable rather than possessing a point, omits Jesus from its criticisms, although it still got banned in Ireland. That people got angry about the movie and took it literally just gives it cred and shifts the emphasis to the Christian satire, which completely displaces the fact we know the movie is making fun of them by comparing them to moralising left-wingers (communists). The film implicitly defends Jesus, it doesn't defend left-wing liberation movements (despite using the names of real-world political parties as metaphors). Comedy, like other forms of debate, is equal opportunity until it isn't.

Decades after the release of *Life of Brian*, Monty Python's skits have a few dated elements. We might imagine EF's critic, who grew up with Monty Python as pushing the boundaries of tasteful and who now sees a world where rape jokes get more mainstream criticism, sees Monty Python as still possessing that scandalous, too-hot-to-handle nature. There are lots of real-world examples of this with comedy, to this critic it might seem that people are getting soft or another sacred cow is presiding (like the left-wingers Monty Python makes fun of). So I think it's a really compelling reference, personally.

### The rest of the list as contrast

This isn't about Monty Python any more, but it is relevant to the instructive contrast. The cultural icons are all pretty well-chosen, and the running list links together the separate styles of criticism. There are lots of commonalities between the groups (Swinburne; various great artists; Monty Python) that invite comparison and contrast. Cultural identity and significance, personal life (Monty Python continue to subvert the list by being a troupe), and so on.

The second sentence depicts critics who are baffled by the premise that anything is wrong with the English at all; they defensively cling to the Renaissance/Enlightenment canon as a claim to broader cultural greatness. The third sentence shows someone directly rejecting EF's intellectual argument because it's annoying. The fourth sentence shows someone just outright dismissing the idea that English sexual mores are Christian rather than just proper (because they're normalised - you don't have to do any more intellectual work than claiming something is 'bollocks' if you're relying on the fact that your audience agrees with you, and the slang invokes a a shared anti-intellectualism, seemingly - public use of slang belongs to the masses, though, so that's very implicit)

So, Swinburne - his legacy is overshadowed by his sexuality, because it's a major part of his art to begin with. His real world sexuality remains shocking when you consider him as a transgressively sexual author within the Victorians, which obviously he was, but it's the 2020s. That art and the artist are hard to separate only makes them more powerful examples of Hilary Mantel's points - if something already has the appeal of popular symbols, using them as a symbol of those things is layers away from reality.

Shakespeare, da Vinci, Dante, Beethoven, and Newton have something crucial in common: they are, in some sense, autobiographically pure, they exemplify a life of greatness untainted by controversy (particularly the sexual/romantic), which lets people revere them as unifying cultural symbols over *centuries*. (Monty Python isn't that legitimately sanitised.)

Shakespeare's sexuality has a Wikipedia page because of this; Dante's relationship with Beatrice is perfect courtly love; da Vinci and Newton didn't form relationships with women. Beethoven embodies the tragic Romantic about as popularly as Byron, but in a different way. Byron's possible bisexuality is overshadowed by his reputation as a *Don Juan*, meanwhile. There aren't any really ambiguous people like Byron in that list, by design - and the choice of Swinburne is perhaps because pointing to someone else might seem too fundamentally irrelevant/wrong as a critique, whereas these sexualities generally *do* relate to the famous works, if only indirectly.

You can get super deep with this, I love this passage. Thanks for posting, and reading (if anyone does)!

Rest in peace, Hilary Mantel, an interesting public figure whose works I deeply enjoy.

Comment: ‘ to instruct as in to teach; that concept is old-fashioned’. In what sense is this ‘old fashioned’?

Comment: Is there something missing in "pointing to someone like else might seem too fundamentally irrelevant/wrong"?

Comment: Spagirl: Sorry, that was poorly articulated! I meant that education has changed (even at a university level), the instruction itself is old-fashioned. So 'instruct', 'teach', and the sense of guidance/cultivation are more semantically decoupled now (except, perhaps, in the context of this kind of lecturer). And I thought that was a potential source of confusion.

Tsundoku: No, the 'like' is an editing error I made because it was late when I posted it. (Thanks for improving my Markdown/fixing that other typo. I'm not a frequent visitor; I appreciate the help a lot.)

Comment: Another great answer! I hope you'll become a more frequent visitor; your contributions so far have been brilliant, exactly the kind of thing we want to see more of on this site.